# Get out of root conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Once I have installed miniconda, I am permanently inside the root miniconda environment eg:

```
luc@montblanc:~$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
bunnies                  /home/luc/miniconda3/envs/bunnies
expose                   /home/luc/miniconda3/envs/expose
testano                  /home/luc/miniconda3/envs/testano
testcondaenv             /home/luc/miniconda3/envs/testcondaenv
root                  *  /home/luc/miniconda3
```

Which results on the use of this environment python3 executable:

```
luc@montblanc:~$ which python3
/home/luc/miniconda3/bin/python3
```

How can I get out of this root environment without actually uninstalling python. E.g. I want

```
luc@montblanc:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

and refer to the miniconda distribution of python explicitly (using full path `/home/luc/miniconda3/bin/python3`) when I need it.

I don't want to achieve any final goal doing this, I just want to understand what is happening and how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See your .bashrc file. Miniconda adds their paths and change the default, find this file and then change or add the path you want, or remove the anaconda/miniconda path.

In your .bashrc (probably ~/.bashrc) you will see something like:

```
# added by Miniconda3 4.3.14 installer
export PATH="/path/to/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Add your path after this line, change this path or, for temporarily, use `export` on command line.

**Obs.**

- After this, probably you will have to use miniconda call by full
  path.
- Restart your session after changes in .bashrc.

Comment: I had to restart the terminal after commenting this line. But it finally works, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can also just use conda deactivate.  For a regular python environment, deactivate or source deactivate should work, but if you try that, you get a hint to use conda deactivate instead.

```
(base) mooreb@ubtest2:~$ deactivate
DeprecationWarning: 'source deactivate' is deprecated. Use 'conda deactivate'.
(base) mooreb@ubtest2:~$ conda deactivate
mooreb@ubtest2:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this on the fly without editing one's init files:

```
    (base) ➜  ~ which python
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python
    (base) ➜  ~ echo $PATH
    /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin:/home/xxx/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
 (base) ➜  ~ export PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '/conda/ {next} {print}' | sed 's/:*$//')
    (base) ➜  ~ echo $PATH                                                                
    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    (base) ➜  ~ which python
    /usr/bin/python
    (base) ➜  ~
```