# command not found: django-admin

Tags: python, django

I have downloaded anaconda and Django, but VS code shows

*ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?*

so, I check out [Get out of root conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696676/get-out-of-root-conda-environment) and [Problem with django after installing anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164669/problem-with-django-after-installing-anaconda), installed django in virtual environment. Then follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/install/. But I can't check out version by''' django-admin.py --version''' it shows ***command not found: django-admin***

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you're calling django with the system's python and not the one inside your virtualenv.

Activate your virtualenv and then type:

```
python -m pip install django
```

That's it! Django will be recognized.

**Also, when wanting to check django version, just simply do:**

```
django-admin --version
```

**without the .py piece**

Remember to always call python inside your virtualenv. Let's say, like so:

```
python .\manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you describe, I believe that you didn't activate the env or you don't have one in your directory, run this command `py -m venv env && .\env\Scripts\activate` then `python -m pip install Django` to create an env and activated and install Django if you have an env in your directory you need to activate using this `.\env\Scripts\activate` and then install Django finally run server Django using `py manage.py runserver` should works.

Comment: How to solve: command not found: .envScriptsactivate

Comment: If you run this command `py -m venv env` you must have a folder called env if you are on Linux the command to activate an env is different

Comment: `source env/bin/activate`